# SQL SUM FROM TWO TABLE

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I've got two tables called invoices and payments..

I want to SUM all invoices made for the user then **minus** all payments made for that user.

```
$sql = "
SELECT bill_to_id
     , SUM(invoices.invoice_total) - SUM(payments.amount) AS razlika 
  FROM invoices  
  JOIN payments 
    ON invoices.bill_to_id = payments.userID   
 GROUP 
    BY invoices.bill_to_id
"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Result of code above is OK for the SUM of total invoices, BUT it's NOT OK for SUM of payments. It's getting multiplied for some reason..

Invoices DB looks like this.

```
bill_to_id         invoice_total
1                  5000.00
2                  3000.00
1                  4000.00
1                  2000.00
```

Payments DB looks like this

```
userID             amount
1                  1500
2                  3000
```

Comment: Whats uplate and whats idfirme in  uplate.idfirme? Please be consistent.

Comment: @P.Salmon uplate is like payments DB and idfirme is like userID in same DB.. I've updated the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should aggregate separately in the 2 tables and then perform the join.

But, I believe that it is easier with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT bill_to_id, SUM(invoice_total) AS razlika
FROM (
  SELECT i.bill_to_id, i.invoice_total 
  FROM invoices i
  WHERE i.bill_to_id <> 1
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM uplate u WHERE u.idfirme = i.bill_to_id)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT u.idfirme, -u.iznos
  FROM uplate u
  WHERE u.idfirme <> 1 
) t
GROUP BY bill_to_id
```

I assume that all payments have a corresponding invoice.
You may remove `AND EXISTS (...)` if you want the total even if for invoices for which there is no payment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've tried it but still not working.

Comment: @Mume see my edited answer and the demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4hJ1x2Sho4m6TJH9WJFz3W/0